# How to replace all RegEx patterns with a new string based on the original sting - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

In my web site, the user can enter a comment. If this comment contains a URL, I need to replace this URL with a link to this URL.
**For example:**
from:

```
Hi guys, you can visit me website at: http://foo.com for more info
```

to:

```
Hi guys, you can visit me website at: <a href="http://foo.com">http://foo.com</a> for more info
```

I use RegEx to find all the URLs in the string, but how can I replace each URL (RegEx pattern) with a new string based on the current URL.

**For example:**

```
var urlRegEx = /(...)/g; // a very long regex pattern that matches urls
var staticText = "bla bla bla http://foo.bar bla bla bla";
var hyperText = staticText.replace(urlRegEx, "<a href='" + urlRegEx + "'/>" + urlRegEx + "</a>"); // This of course will not work!!! :-(
```

I'm looking for a solution with RegExs. In addition yes I know I can save the value of `RegEx.exec(staticText)[0]` in a new parameter inside a loop and replace them one by one, but can I do this **without** looping on the string???

Comment: `"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"`. Next!

Comment: [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Description) -> _"The replacement string can include the following special replacement patterns: ..."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var hyperText = staticText.replace(urlRegEx, "<a href='$0'/>$0</a>");
```

When executing the method `RegEx.protptype.exec(string)` you will get a `match` object (which is an Array) that contains the value that matches the RegEx's pattern. You can access the values of this array using $i there `i` is the index of the match array.

Therefore to access to **compete** value of the matching pattern, access the 0 index - $0

Comment: ...that makes your capturing brackets pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is surrounded by parenthesis because you want to capture it. In order to use the captured value, you must reference it using `$1`:

```
var urlRegEx = /(...)/g;
var staticText = "bla bla bla http://foo.bar bla bla bla";
var hyperText = staticText.replace(urlRegEx, "<a href='$1'/>$1</a>");
                                                       ^^   ^^
```